# Add subview to UITableViewCell on selection

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to add a UIView that is supposed to strikethrough the text (don't worry about the horizontal misplacement).

However, when selecting a row, the line is added several rows below. Why?

[image: Strange selection behaviour]

Here's my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = cell.textLabel;

    CGSize textSize = [[label text] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[label font]}];
    CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;

    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.height / 2, 200, strikeWidth, 2)];
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    lineView.tag = 100;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a UIView and adding a subview to the cell, you should use an `NSAttributedString` for the cell text and the `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` to strike through with an `NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName` for the strikethrough colour.

Comment: This only sets the attributed text while the cell is selected (when hold your finger on the cell). Once removing your finger the strikethrough is removed. Do I have to switch from using `cell.textLabel.text` to `cell.textLabel.attributedText` ?

Comment: Yes you should set your UILabel's attributedText property (presumably in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, where the cell is created).

Comment: I found the issue. I'm not updating Core Data, and `[tableView reloadData]` runs `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which runs `[self configureCell]` where I set the `cell.textLabel.text` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.height / 2, 200, strikeWidth, 2)];
```

In this case, "self" is the tableViewController, not the label or the cell. What you're doing is setting the x origin of the view as half the *height* of the screen, the y origin down 200 points, with a width of *strikeWidth* and a height of 2.

Because the line view you are adding is going to be a subview of the cell, you always want to make the frame relative to it's superview, which in this case is the cell itself. You likely want to use something like similar to below:

```
CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(cell.textLabel.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.contentView.frame) / 2, strikeWidth, 2)
```

You'll likely want to tweak values to make it line up, but you get the idea...

EDIT: Better frame added and here's more code that does it nicely:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = cell.textLabel;

    CGSize textSize = [[label text] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[label font]}];
    CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;

    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(label.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.contentView.frame) / 2, strikeWidth, 2)];
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: I think you're right, but probably wrong that self is the tableView.

Comment: No, self IS the tableView.

Comment: Really?  In what class do you suppose this tableview delegate code appears?

Comment: No, self is definitely not the tableView, it's the view controller.

Comment: Sorry, I MEANT the table view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think your line is appearing outside of your cell because you set an y origin of 200 in your frame, which seems pretty high.

Moreover, if you want to play with strikethrough in a UITableviewCell, you'd better not do it this way, because on multiple selection this 'strikethroughView' will be added multiple times, and never removed. Also on a tableview reloadData, or scrolling the cells are reused, and you don't want to see these strikethroughViews randomly displayed.

Here are two ways to do it properly :

- Use the NSAttributedString framework. Basically if allows you to do all sorts of things to a string, like setting color, background color, paragraph style, but also strikeThrough.
  Here is what i would write in the didSelect delegate method :

  ```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSString *string = cell.textLabel.text;

  NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleThick)};
  NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
  cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString; 
  }
  ```
- The other solution would be to add a Category on UICollectionViewCell and implement a "setStrikeTrough" method in it.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Good solution, the only thing I would change is instead of a subclass of UICollectionViewCell I would create a category on UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: You're right, far simpler since it's just a method. I'll make the edit.